# Communication between Two process using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, wcf, data-binding, ipc

I have a windows form application with the grid displaying data from MySql database.

I have one more application running on the background which is connected to an external application through an Api provided by the external application.this application updates the same database on certain event happened on the external application.

Now the problem is whenever the background app updates the database the same has to get reflected in the datagrid without refreshing the grid. i.e. Data has to get updated on realtime.

Have gone through binding the grid with datatable but i dint find any workaround for MYsql.

Have also checked with inter process communication so that i can make the background application to update the DB as well as the foreground application. there are so many options showing for IPC but i couldn't make out the best suitable for my current requirement.

It would be very helpful if anybody suggest a best possible workaround for this problem.

Note: Fore ground is a winform application runs on .Net 3.5 and background console application on .net4.0 because of the compatibility issue with the api of the external application.

Comment: Where does WCF come into this question?

Comment: have heard WCF can be used for inter process communication..

Comment: To clarify - you have a database which is queried directly from a WinForms application. The WinForms application displays the data from the database in a grid. You have another application which can update the database. You want the grid to update at the same time?

Comment: http://dotnet-experience.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/inter-process-duplex-communication-with.html

Answer (score -1):

For what im understand , you trying to synchronize the table update for datagrid.

My suggestion is to use :

```
datagrid.refresh();
```

and bind it into timer to refresh every second or minutes.

Comment: This does not address the OPs problem. The problem is not refreshing the grid, but refreshing the grid in response to changes to an underlying database in real-time, where the data can be changed at any time.